# Python – cleaning CSV file with split records

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a delimited file in which some of the fields contain line termination characters. They can be LF or CR/LF.

The line terminators cause the records to split over multiple lines.

My objective is to read the file, remove the line termination characters, then write out a delimited file with quotes around the fields.

Sample input record:

```
444,2018-04-06,19:43:47,43762485,"Request processed"CR\LF

555,2018-04-30,19:17:56,43762485,"Added further note:LF

email customer a receipt" CR\LF
```

The first record is fine but the second has a LF (line feed) causing the record to fold.

```
import csv

with open(raw_data, 'r', newline='') as inp, open(csv_data, 'w') as out:
    csvreader = csv.reader(inp, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in csvreader:
        print(str(row))
        out.write(str(row)[1:-1] + '\n')
```

My code nearly works but I don’t think it is correct.

The output I get is:

```
['444', '2020-04-06', '19:43:47', '344376882485', 'Request processed']

['555', '2020-04-30', '19:17:56', '344376882485', 'Added further note:\nemail customer a receipt']
```

I use the substring to remove the square brackets at the start and end of the line which I think is not the correct way.
Notice on the second record the new line character has been converted to \n. I would like to know how to get rid of that and also incorporate a csv writer to the code to place double quoting around the fields.

To remove the line terminators I tried replace but did not work.

```
(row.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '') for row in csvreader)
```

I also tried to incorporate a csv writer but could not get it working with the list.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet does what you want:

```python
with open('raw_data.csv', 'r', newline='') as inp, open('csv_data.csv', 'w') as out:
    reader = csv.reader(inp, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for row in reader:
        fixed = [cell.replace('\n', '') for cell in row]
        writer.writerow(fixed)
```

Quoting all cells is handled by passing [csv.QUOTE_ALL](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_ALL) as the writer's "quoting" argument.

The line

```
fixed = [cell.replace('\n', '') for cell in row]
```

creates a new list of cells where embedded `'\n'` characters are replaced by the empty string.

By default, Python will set the end-of-line to your platform's default.  If you want to override this you can pass a [lineterminator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator) argument to the writer.

To me the original csv seems fine: it's normal to have embedded newlines ("soft line-breaks") inside quoted cells, and csv-aware applications should as spreadsheets will handle them correctly.  However they will look wrong in applications that don't understand csv formatting and so treat the embedded newlines as actual end of line characters.